# grabbing div id by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `$('.startb').click(function() {
var myId = $(this).attr("id");
});` to capture the id "startb1" what do I need to add to also capture the id "test1" by the class "flashObj" by using the fact they are all in the same div container "audioContainer"

```
<div class="audioContainer">
            <div class="audioTitle">hi</div>
            <div class="playerHolder">
            <div class="startb" id="startb1" rel="Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3"><img src="dbs/images/start.png" width="40" height="40" /></div>
            <div class="flashObj" id="test1"></div>
            <div class="mp3Logo"><a href="Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3"><img src="dbs/images/mp3_off.gif"/></a></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for siblings of the div having the class `flashObj`:

```
$('.startb').click(function() { 
   var myId = $(this).attr("id"); 
   var flashObjID = $(this).siblings('.flashObj').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: dang beat me to it. I would use this snippet.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myId = this.id;
var otherId = this.parentNode.querySelector(".flashObj").id;
```

This method of getting the "startb1" id is approximately 150 times more efficient than yours, due to the amount of steps jQuery has to go through just to create the `$(this)` object, by the way.

Also, `querySelector` is supported in IE8 whereas `getElementsByClassName` isn't.

If IE7 and below is required, and the structure is reliable (ie. it will always be the fourth child `div` you need), use: `var otherId = this.parentNode.children[3].id;`.

Comment: +1 for using the far more efficient `this.id` instead of the verbose and inefficient `$(this).attr(id)`

Answer (score 1):

Use .on() instead of .click() if you are using latest jQuery release:

```
$(".audioContainer").on("click", ".startb", function(e){
    var _this = $(this);
    var id = _this.attr("id");
    var oId = _this.closest(".audioContainer").find(".flashObj").attr("id");
}
```

Now you can also map multiple events, keep events for later on and even pass data to the event.data object and etc.

Read more at: [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the same "click" event, the following should do the trick:

```
$('.startb').click(function() {
    var myId = $(this).attr("id");
    var flashID = $(this).parent().find(".flashObj").attr("id");
});
```